# In python, how to extract some char from each item of a list ?

Tags: python, list

In python, how to extract some char from each item of a list ?

e.g. in a list, each item (modelName) has

```
  cfn99e1195_1.lp
```

The numbers inside may be different.

I need to get 99 and 1195.

I tried

```
 findN = modelName.find('n')  
 findE = modelName.find('e')
 nodeNum = modelName(findN, findE) 
 findBar = modelName.find('_')  
 arcNum = modelName(findE, findBar)
```

does not work.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using regular expressions:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^cfn(\d+)e(\d+)')
a, b = pattern.match('cfn99e1195_1.lp').groups()
```

Comment: modelName = array[0], a, b = pattern.match(modelName).groups() , I got error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: That means the pattern failed to match against the string. What is array[0] ?

Comment: for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, 'cfn*e*_1.lp_obj_node_arc.txt') ):
      print "current file is: " + infile
  array = []
      for line in infile:
          #array.append( line )
   array = line.split()
   break

Comment: array[0] is got from line.split(), line is read from a file .

Comment: Well, I mean the content of array[0]. Would you print array[0] to tell me what the string is? Sorry for the previous ambiguity.

Comment: array[0] is ['/'] but it should be cfn99e1195_1.lp, so something wrong with for line in infile:
   array.append(line) ?

Comment: Would you please paste part of your `.lp` file and your source code in your question.

Comment: It works, I forgot infile = open(infile, "r" ). but, how to print the modelName, a, b in the same line ? " print >>outPutFile , modelName, a, b" print a , b, at new line. thanks

Comment: Maybe there is a '\n' at the end of modelName? Try `print >> outPutFile, modelName.strip(), a, b`

Comment: thanks, it works, but I have never put '\n' after modelName. it is weird.

Comment: modelName is the last world in each line of your file, right? Then there will be a '\n'.

Comment: Also, if it works, remember to upvote or accept my answer by clicking the arrows on the left, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The groupdict could be more illustrative, also a check if the match is really there:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^cfn(?P<a>\d+)e(?P<b>\d+)')
m = pattern.match('cfn99e1195_1.lp')
d = {}
if m:
    d = m.groupdict()

# the result will be in the form {'a': '99', 'b': '1195'}
# or {} if not matched
```

OF course, the patter could be reused for all similar matching operations.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
nodeNum = modelName(findN, findE)
```

doesn't make much sense. You're trying to call the string here as if it were a function.

What you want is this:

```
nodeNum = modelName[findN + 1: findE]
```

But remember that `.find()` can return `-1` if the substring wasn't found.

So at the very least, replace `.find()` with `.index()` which does the same thing but raises an exception instead if the substring is not found.

You might also want to consider using regular expressions to extract the numbers.